# run chkdsk from linux partition of wubi install

Tags: linux, windows, chkdsk

I have installed linux using the wubi installer, and recently my Windows partition became corrupt (hangs during boot). I would like to run chkdsk on it to try and fix it, but I cannot figure out a way to schedule it from the linux boot. I have also tried running ntfsfix, but I cannot unmount the windows partition (it always says it is busy even after I closed any processes running on it). I suspect this has something to do with the fact that I installed linux using wubi.

I have also tried booting using a windows cd to the recovery console but  before it gets to the recovery console I get a blue screen error.

Is there another way to fix the windows disk without reformatting?

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to boot the Windows CD and use recovery console's chkdsk if at all possible.
Booting a Linux live CD like the [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/) to use ntfsfix would also work if you do not have the Windows CD or does not support your hard disk controller.

Comment: Whenever I try to book to the dinwos cd, i get a blue screen error before I can even get to the recovery console (or before I'm given the option to install). i can try systemrescuecd

Comment: The STOP screen, probably 0x0000007B, is most likely caused by your system using SATA disk and Windows not having drivers for it. You can *temporarily* switch your disks to IDE in the BIOS to execute chkdsk and don't forget to switch them back to SATA/AHCI/RAID as it was before to prevent Windows from using IDE as principal driver in the future.

Comment: I tried switching to IDE, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Ugly solution would be to create a custom boot disk using nLite, vLite, and any of its variants with required drivers slipstreamed on to the disk. This should get past the BSOD error unless it is a hardware error. Else use different/indepedent OS as mentioned to run file system checking utilities.

Comment: I ended up just wiping the disk. Thanks though.